# cURL: How do I know if my cookies are being set properly?

Tags: php, curl

```
$ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
$useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16";

$ch = curl_init ("website.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$output = curl_exec ($ch);
```

The website sets a cookie and then redirects. Would this code suffice? Because it seems to be not getting the cookie properly. How can I check to see if it's set? Better yet, if I know what cookies I want can I just make it or something?

Edit: So my CURL script visits the website right? The website sets cookies for validation, and I want to see if my cURL script is receiving those cookies properly. I want to know if there's a test for that, and/or I want to know if I can just create a cookie to validate for the website.

Comment: I should really proof read my posts before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had a project where I needed to pass cookies between servers, and I found that setting both `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` to the same file did the trick.

If you're just wanting to see if the cookies from the remote site are being set, you should be able to look at the `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` file in a text editor.

Answer (score 1):

If this were the command line curl you'd throw in the `-v` parameter. Pay attention to the lines starting with `> Cookie:`.

The php version of this is:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,TRUE);//and set CURLOPT_STDERR to STDOUT
```

And if this were a browser I would debug with one of these: you can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) on IE, [TamperData](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966) or [Firebug (net)](http://getfirebug.com/net.html) on Firefox, the inspector [on Chrome](http://blog.chromium.org/2009/06/developer-tools-for-google-chrome.html) and [on Safari](http://www.playingwithwire.com/2009/06/safari-4-launches-new-developer-tools/), or a [proxy](http://www.google.com/search?q=debug+proxy) with any browser to watch how the form is submitted by a "normal" browser.

The proxy approach might work if you set php's curl to use it.

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL,TRUE);//& CURLOPT_PROXYPORT CURLOPT_PROXY
```

If you want to just add cookies to one request you could write a line like:

```
$ch->headers[] = 'Cookie: recent=543..; _session_id=6185..; __utma=572.1.1.1.1; __utmc=572..; __utmz=572.1.1.1.1.utmccn=(referral)|utmcsr=domain.com|utmcct=/request/path|utmcmd=referral';
```

but I'm not certain about that one, these might be more along the same line:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIE,"recent=543..; _session_id=618..");
// Possibly, but I think this might overwrite other headers.
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, "Cookie: recent=543..; _session_id=6185..");
```

Comment: Unfortunately I think I'm confused about what specifically is not working in your question? Is it that you're receiving a cookie in the cookie jar and then you want to check if you're using that cookie that was set? Then I'd use the verbose or proxy methods.